# Reaction of alkynes with sodium in liquid ammonia

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity

#### Problem

> The hydrocarbon which can react with sodium in liquid ammonia is?
>
> (**A**) $\ce{CH3CH2C#CH}$
> (**B**) $\ce{CH3CH=CHCH3}$
> (**C**) $\ce{CH3CH2C#CCH2CH3}$
> (**D**) $\ce{CH3CH2CH2C#CCH2CH2CH3}$

#### Answer

> (**A**) $\ce{CH3CH2C#CH}$

#### Question

I am confused why the answer cant be (**C**) or (**D**) since these two could undergo reaction with sodium in ammonia to give me *trans*-alkenes as products.

Comment: Well, I guess they missed this possibility.

Comment: Similar to this (even poorer) question Similar to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94716/which-of-the-following-react-with-sodium-in-liquid-ammonia. The one marked in red in the picture that you have included is the only which doesn't occur.

Comment: @Alchimista Ah so i think the question itself has ambiguity. Also yes, i know the second reaction wont undergo birch reduction, i mis clicked option lol.

Comment: @Alchimista Nicely found. Well, I guess we can safely close this as a dupe and solve the $\ce{#CH3}$ mystery once and for all.

Comment: Poorer in my first comment referred to the quiz not really to the SE questions. @Andselisk yes its a kind of duplicate.

Answer (score -5):

You are correct.

Na/NH3 is a standard method for reducing internal alkynes to *trans* (*E*) alkenes.

More reading [here](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch09/ch9-7.html) and [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/09%3A_Alkynes_-_An_Introduction_to_Organic_Synthesis/9.05%3A_Reduction_of_Alkynes)